# IDE o Gema Arcadia tira error [Windows 7]

Tags: windows, ruby, rubygems, ide

Tuve el siguiente problema una vez instalada la gema ***`arcadia`*** cuando escribo en la consola de Windows (CMD):

```
Arcadia requeri ruby-tk extension and tcl/tk run-time you must install before run.
----- LoadError Details ------------------
Plataform :  "i386-mingw32"
Ruby version: "2.3.1"
Message: "cannot load such file -- tk"
```

Comment: Solo decir que esa gema lleva sin ser mantenida ya [hace más de un año](https://github.com/angal/arcadia/commits/master), creo hay muchas mejores opciones ahí afuera para desarrollar en ruby.  De hecho si puedes usa Mac o instala un Linux en tu equipo, porque te espera un mundo de dolor desarrollando Ruby en Windows

Comment: Si lo que te digo aún no te convence, prueba a llevar a cabo las [indicaciones de la wiki](https://github.com/angal/arcadia/wiki/windows-users) para instalar en Windows. Al parecer no tienes instaladas las librerías de tcl/tk

Comment: Tengo uan pc con linux, pero por motivos apartes no tengo conexión a internet y probaba dicha gema. De todas formas muchas gracias ^^.

PD: ¿Qué otra Gema como IDE o Editor para ruby recomiendas?

Comment: En mis inicios usé Aptana radrails como IDE, pero como está basado en eclipse es bastante lento en uso, así que a decir verdad hace mucho que no uso un IDE para ruby. Como la gran mayoría, uso un editor para desarrollo en ruby y hay varias opciones: Sublime Text 3 (el que uso yo), Atom, vim, Xcode o RubyMine como IDE en mac.